# Command 'restart' not found

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to configure Linux Network-Manager GUI for OpenVPN. I'm following the instructions from ubuntu's server [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openvpn.html.en). I tried to install it using the following command and realized it's already present in my system.

```
root@apoorv:~# apt install network-manager-openvpn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
network-manager-openvpn is already the newest version (1.8.2-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 51 not upgraded.
```

According to the instructions,

> To inform network-manager about the new installed packages you will have to restart it

But when I restart it, I get the following error:

```
root@apoorv:~# restart network-manager

Command 'restart' not found, did you mean:

  command 'rstart' from deb x11-session-utils
  command 'restartd' from deb restartd

Try: apt install <deb name>
```

Then I tried this:

```
root@apoorv:~# systemctl restart network-manager
```

But it seems like nothing happened.

What am I supposed to do here? How can I set up open VPN on ubuntu 18.04? I've been trying to find a free VPN for ubuntu for weeks now but always tend to fail to configure it because of how complex things get. Are there any easily configurable VPNs for noobs?

Answer (score 1):

> `root@apoorv:~# systemctl restart network-manager`
>   But it seems like nothing happened.

Then that is correct. Expected behaviour in Linux is to not show output if all went well and only show something when there is a problem.

Besides that: "restart" is an option to the command "service". So:

```
service network-manager restart
service network-manager stop
service network-manager start
```

are also valid methods of addressing a service.

Comment: I tried it. It didn't show any output. Assuming that everything went well, I tried to test it by accessing [steam community](https://store.steampowered.com/)(since I can't access it normally on my current campus wifi because of its restrictions). But it won't load up. So should I assume here that the VPN isn't working? Also how can I open the nework manager GUI?

Comment: You have to configure a VPN connection, and enable that connection as well...